# CakePHP 3 refresh session data

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a page where i can modify user details (username,first name,avatar...).
I have an element in my navbar with informations about the currently logged in user. The thing is I can't figure out how to refresh the session immediately after data is modified.

in **UsersController**:

```
public function edit($id = null)
{
    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
    }

    $user = $this->Users->get($id);
    if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) {
        $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {

            //REFRESH SESSION ????\\
            $this->request->session()->write('Auth.User', $user);
            //\\

            $this->Flash->success(__('User has been updated.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'edit/' . $id]);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to update User details.'));
    }

    $this->set(compact('user'));
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just update it the same way as you're setting it when loggin in, ie using `AuthComponent::setUser()`.

Also you may want to do that only in case the user that has been edited, is actually the user that is currently logged in. And you want to set the data in the same format as the Auth component does, that is (for now), as an array, and, for security purposes, without the password.

A simple example that assumes a single column primary key named `id`, and a password column named `password`

```
if ($this->Auth->user('id') === $user->id) {
    $data = $user->toArray();
    unset($data['password']);

    $this->Auth->setUser($data);
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Components > Authentication > Identifying Users and Logging Them In](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in)**
- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Components > Authentication > Manually Logging Users In](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#manually-logging-users-in)**

Comment: `unset($data['password'])` shouldn't be necessary because it should be in the hidden property inside your entity.

Comment: @StefanD. In an ideal world that would be the case, however that bake feature was broken until a month ago (bake 1.1.4), and people might even not use bake, and/or use columns other than `token`, `password` and `passwd` (which is what bake detects), so I'd say it's still worth mentioning that people should watch out for this.